# Laravel File Storage delete all files in directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, file-storage

Is there a way to delete all files in specific directory. I'm trying to clear all my files in my created folder backgrounds in storage\app\backgrounds but in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#deleting-files) seems no method for delete all.

```
Storage::delete('backgrounds\*.jpg');
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't think if this is the best way to solve this. But I solved mine calling

```
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
```

Then initiate new instance

```
$file = new Filesystem;
$file->cleanDirectory('storage/app/backgrounds');
```

Answer (score 27):

for Laravel >= 5.8

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

    // Get all files in a directory
    $files =   Storage::allFiles($dir);

    // Delete Files
    Storage::delete($files);
```

Comment: It has been tried with Laravel 5.8 and it is working fine. I used it for my Task Schecduler.

Answer (score 25):

Just use it.

```
 File::cleanDirectory($direction);
```

Comment: This is the way.

Comment: Note he is using the Facade 'File' (`use File;` or better `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`). 
You can also use this in conjunction with Storage disks: `File::cleanDirectory(Storage::disk('some-disk')->path(''));`

Answer (score 7):

You can use Filesystem method cleanDirectory

```
$success = Storage::cleanDirectory($directory);
```

Please see documentation for more information:

https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_cleanDirectory

Comment: Thanks for the hint `cleanDirectory` but does not actually solve calling those `Storage::cleanDirectory` giving me an error `League\Flysystem\Filesystem::cleanDirectory`.

Comment: This method does **not** exist statically on the `Storage` facade.

Comment: Call to undefined method League\Flysystem\Filesystem::cleanDirectory
laravel 6

Answer (score 5):

In **Laravel 5.8** you can use:

```
Storage::deleteDirectory('backgrounds');
```

Remember to include:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

Comment: Actually, this deletes the directory itself too.

Answer (score 3):

In **Laravel 5.7** you can empty a directory using the `Storage` facade like so:

```
Storage::delete(Storage::files('backgrounds'));

$dirs = Storage::directories('backgrounds');

foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    Storage::deleteDirectory($dir);
}
```

The `delete()` method can receive an array of files to delete, while `deleteDirectory()` deletes one directory (and its contents) at a time.

I don't think it's a good idea to delete and then re-create the directory as that can lead to unwanted race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm handling this by deleting the whole directory as I don't need it. But if, for any case, you need the directory you should be good by just recreating it:

```
$d = '/myDirectory'
Storage::deleteDirectory($d);
Storage::makeDirectory($d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem and it's method cleanDirectory('path_to_directory).
For Example:
    $FolderToDelete = base_path('path_to_your_directory');
    $fs = new \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
    $fs->cleanDirectory($FolderToDelete);   
    //For Delete All Files From  Given Directory.
    $succes = rmdir($FolderToDelete);
    //For Delete Directory
    //This Method Works for me

#Laravel 
#FileManager
#CleanDirectory
```