# Delete All Files Except 'placeholder.png' in folder using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to figure this all out here. I've seen this post below about how to delete all files within a directory, however I want to exclude my placeholder image from this deletion. I haven't come across the answer I'm looking for yet on SO, so this is just going to be a short and simple question.

Take a look at this SO question here: [Laravel File Storage delete all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007356/laravel-file-storage-delete-all-files-in-directory)

Comment: you can apply check if placeholder.png exist in directory then except that delete all, you just have to make your placeholder image unique name.

Answer (score 3):

[`delete()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L175) accepts an array of files for deletion. Thus, one possible solution is listing the directory with a wildcard selector, then filter out your exclusion list from the array.

```
$filesForDelete = array_filter(glob("path/to/files/*"), function($file) {
    return false === strpos($file, 'placeholder.png');
});

Storage::delete($filesForDelete);
```

Of course, your filter expression may become better, broader, or just do the same thing in many other ways.

For example, you may create a helper function like this:

```
function deleteAllButFile($exclude)
{
    $filesForDelete = array_filter(glob("path/to/files/*"), function($file) use ($exclude) {
        return false === strpos($file, $exclude);
    });
    Storage::delete($filesForDelete);
}

// Call it like
deleteAllButFile('placeholder.png');
```

Or any other way you like. Up to your imagination.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow after I get off work. If I can implement it successfully you'll definitely get the answer and an upvote from me! Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: Also maybe you could help with this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940859/laravel-faker-image-save-to-multiple-directories-with-same-filename